# Git commits with the incorrect name

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have a personal account on GitHub and an organization. But my recent project is a personal project and not owned by my organization. Unfortunately my last commit is owned by my organization. I tried to change my name (`git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"`). But there's everything right. Why does Git commit with my organization name and how do I change this?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you change `user.name` for the repo (`git config --local ...`).

```
$ git config --list
# Find 'user.name' and 'user.email'
```

**Change Commit Author:**

```
$ git commit --amend --author "New-author-name <new-author@mail.com>"
$ git push -f origin HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's everything right. There is my private Mail and Name.

Comment: Is there any change, you committed from other machine and pull the commit on this machine? Can you add another test commit and check what the `author` name is?

Comment: Thank you for your help. My latest commit is fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your settings in GitHub and add your organization email address there, under the Emails tab. This way you will get all your work committed under your organization name displayed there.

Change your user name and user email using command

```
git config --global user.name "name"
git config --global user.email "email-address"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly the problem. I don't want to commit in name of my organization.

Comment: You cannot change the commits that you did under the name of your organization. By changing the settings, you will escape from doing that in future. 
Whatever commits that happened under your org name, you can add them as yours by adding your org email in your personal GitHub Account.

Comment: This might help, @LucasHild  https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tested it again and now it works.